# Bolding value at top of stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I would like to bold the summary of my stats that I will be putting at the top of the bar. This code takes the values in the stacked bar and puts their sum at the top.

Here is the code:

```
stat_summary(fun.y = sum, aes(label = ..y.., group = Week, col = "#FF4500"), geom = "text", vjust = -.5)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add an example dataset so we can run the code?  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some ideas on including a reproducible example in your question.

Comment: You might be able to use `fontface = "bold"`

Comment: Yes, `fontface="bold"` will work inside `stat_summary`.

Comment: Thank you everyone, fontface worked. I am surprised I was not able to find it. Simple solution!